# Customized ucwords fails when letter inside parens

Tags: php

I have a glorified `ucwords` function which allows my system to optionally allow/disallow words within a string to be **all caps**:

```
function NormalizeWords($str, $disallowAllUppercase = false){
    $parts = explode(' ', $str);

    if($disallowAllUppercase){
        $result = array_map(function($x){
            return ucwords(strtolower($x));
        }, $parts);
    }else{
        $result = array_map(function($x){
            if (!(strtoupper($x) == $x)) {
                return ucwords(strtolower($x));
            }
            return $x;
        }, $parts);
    }

    return implode(' ', $result);
}
```

This function works in almost all cases. Where it fails is when a word is inside parens (or any non-alphanumeric characters I would assume).

Here are some examples:

```
writeme(NormalizeWords("Make An Omelette (template)", true));
writeme(NormalizeWords("make an omelette (template)", true));
writeme(NormalizeWords("Make An Omelette - template", true));
```

Results:

```
Make An Omelette (template) - wrong
Make An Omelette (template) - wrong
Make An Omelette - Template - right
```

Expected Results:

```
Make An Omelette (Template)
Make An Omelette (Template)
Make An Omelette - Template
```

You can see that when a word/words touch parens or other characters, the first letter doesn't get forced to ucase. How can I fix my function to do this?

Comment: Did you try with `mb_convert_case()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing your function to use `preg_split` to split the string on any non-alphabetic characters, you can extract only the words for capitalisation. By using the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` flag we retain all the non-alphabetic characters and we can then put the string back to together by using `implode` with no glue:

```
function NormalizeWords($str, $disallowAllUppercase = false){
    $parts = preg_split('/([^A-Za-z]+)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    if($disallowAllUppercase){
        $result = array_map(function($x){
            return ucwords(strtolower($x));
        }, $parts);
    }else{
        $result = array_map(function($x){
            if (!(strtoupper($x) == $x)) {
                return ucwords(strtolower($x));
            }
            return $x;
        }, $parts);
    }
    return implode('', $result);
}

echo(NormalizeWords("Make AN Omelette (template)", false)) . PHP_EOL;
echo(NormalizeWords("make AN omelette (template)", true)) . PHP_EOL;
echo(NormalizeWords("Make An Omelette - template", true)) . PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Make AN Omelette (Template)
Make An Omelette (Template)
Make An Omelette - Template
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/o0Joq)

Note you can simplify your function by passing `$disallowAllUppercase` to the `array_map` function:

```
function NormalizeWords($str, $disallowAllUppercase = false){
    $parts = preg_split('/([^A-Za-z]+)/', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $result = array_map(function ($x) use ($disallowAllUppercase) {
        if ($disallowAllUppercase || strtoupper($x) != $x) {
            return ucwords(strtolower($x));
        }
        return $x;
    }, $parts);
    return implode('', $result);
}
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PCYfb)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is do it with simple and one liner
 `mb_convert_case()` function, by the way you can wrap it inside your **NormalizeWords** function.

```
<?php
$text= "Make (an) omelette (template)";
echo mb_convert_case($text, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO**:  https://3v4l.org/NgX6W

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can temporarily replace the parens to unrecognizable words and then put it back after the `NormalizeWords`:

```
$str = 'make an omelette (template)';
$str = str_ireplace('(','unrgcswzbl ',$str); 
$str = str_ireplace(')','unrgcswzbl2 ',$str);
$str = NormalizeWords( $str,true);
$str = str_ireplace('unrgcswzbl ','',$str);
$str = str_ireplace('unrgcswzbl2 ','',$str);
echo $str;
```